# cakephp escape function or mysql_real_escape_string is not safe?

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-injection

Strange problem appeared today on our server.
We've got DDOS from % and _ signs in mysql query which were successfully passed through GET request. For example

```
domain.com/search/%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25v%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25a
```

it appears to be cakephp doesn't filter them? in [official mysql guide](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/guide-to-php-security-ch3.pdf) they write about this problem a lot. that's how they demonstrate to solve this:

```
addcslashes(mysql_real_escape_string(“%something_”), “%_”);
```

in cakephp framework there's function `escape()` which used everywhere in models. and look what it contains:

```
/** 
 * Returns a quoted and escaped string of $data for use in an SQL statement.
 *
 * @param string $data String to be prepared for use in an SQL statement
 * @param string $column The column into which this data will be inserted
 * @param boolean $safe Whether or not numeric data should be handled automagically if no column data is provided
 * @return string Quoted and escaped data
 */ 
    function value($data, $column = null, $safe = false) {
        $parent = parent::value($data, $column, $safe);

        if ($parent != null) {
            return $parent;
        }   
        if ($data === null || (is_array($data) && empty($data))) {
            return 'NULL';
        }   
        if ($data === '' && $column !== 'integer' && $column !== 'float' && $column !== 'boolean') {
            return "''";
        }   
        if (empty($column)) {
            $column = $this->introspectType($data);
        }   

        switch ($column) {
            case 'boolean':
                return $this->boolean((bool)$data);
            break;
            case 'integer' :
            case 'float' :
            case null :
                if ($data === '') {
                    return 'NULL';
                }   
                if (is_float($data)) {                                                                                                               
                    return str_replace(',', '.', strval($data));
                }
                if ((is_int($data) || is_float($data) || $data === '0') || (
                    is_numeric($data) && strpos($data, ',') === false &&
                    $data[0] != '0' && strpos($data, 'e') === false)) {
                        return $data;
                    }
            default:
                $data = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $data) . "'";
            break;
        }   

        return $data;
    }
```

just a basic protection agains some variable types and stuff like this.. what about escaping mysql special characters?? about year ago i read how it's possible to escape quote sign with help of percent sign in mysql query =) It was hype of blind injections back then, and that trick worked pretty much everywhere because everybody use mysqli_real_escape_string.

I must state a question here: How to escape variable in cakephp - REALLY SAFELY?

**update:** some folks in IRC states that REQUEST string must be escaped and not query it self. they probably right, then how can I escape % and _ chars in GET request string without using custom functions.. any sanitize method does it?

Comment: `%` and `_` are only special characters in the context of a `LIKE` comparison. The answer would therefore be quite simple: just `str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\_'), $str)` before passing `$str` into the database for use in a `LIKE` comparison. If it's to be e.g. inserted or used with any other comparison operator, it's not dangerous anyway. Does this actually cause a problem anyway? I would have thought that MySQL would treat any sequence of more than one `%` in a row as a single `%` - although I could be wrong about that.

Comment: yes we just had DDOS with that url on top, that's why it's insanely important. i traced it personally

Comment: Yes but what effect did it actually have? Did it affect MySQL or just the web server process? What was the end bad result of the DDOS attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't mean Cake is susceptible to SQL injection, as it in the underbelly it uses prepared statements, it does mean you are using a `LIKE` search query in CakePHP and it's letting the wildcard characters though.

I don't think this is ideal behaviour as I have found this out while developing too, I just have this line above finds that use `LIKE` now.

```
$term = str_replace('%', ' ', $term);
```

You don't need to take escaping in to your own hands, the framework handles that for you.

Comment: well bottleneck is probably GET request string, so i don't want to use any custom methods for that, I updated the question - any method of cakephp does escaping of % and _ signs in request string?

Answer (score 0):

The code example you show is safe. This line:

```
$data = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $data) . "'";
```

escapes special characters. The method checks for the variable's type - it doesn't need to be escaped if it's not a string.

It would be nice to see a source for the alleged "vulnerability" of `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: The vulnerability in `mysql_real_escape_string()` only appears when you execute a `SET NAMES` query. In this case, the character set evaluation that libmysql does while performing the escape is flawed because the connection character set has changed, but libmysql doesn't know about it and will continue to use the old character set in escape operations. Apart from that it is safe and the problem can be mitigated completely by using `mysql_set_charset()` instead of `SET NAMES`. Yes, the security hole is very small, but it's still a hole.

Comment: @Juhana this function doesn't escape % and _ and we've got DDOS recently because of this chars in get param, im just asking for simple function in CAKEPHP framework which could filter them out in GET string. in my opinion this characters, by default, should be escaped with mysql_real_escape_string() (which is used by sanitazation class in cakephp)

Comment: DDOS has nothing to do with sanitizing. If you use `LIKE`, escape the characters manually. Everywhere else escaping `%` or `_` has no effect. Cake can't escape them automatically, otherwise you couldn't use `LIKE` queries at all.